# Socket.io error - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am trying to build a basic chat html program.
I have set up a node server to test it, however, when accessing the html page, I get an socket error. It's my first time working with node.js and setting up node server, so I've surely done something wrong.

Thanks to everyone who's taking a look at this!

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

var socket = io.listen(1223, "1.2.3.4"); 
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

console.log('Server is running...');
var people = {};  

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

// When connecting
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
 client.on("join", function(name){
  people[client.id] = name;
  client.emit("update", "You have connected to the server.");
  socket.sockets.emit("update", name + " has joined the server.");
  socket.sockets.emit("update-people", people);
 });

// When sending
 client.on("send", function(msg){
  socket.sockets.emit("chat", people[client.id], msg);
 });

// When disconnecting
 client.on("disconnect", function(){
  socket.sockets.emit("update", people[client.id] + " has left the server.");
  delete people[client.id];
  socket.sockets.emit("update-people", people);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS --> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function(){  
        var socket = io.connect("1.2.3.4:1223");
        $("#chat").hide();
        $("#name").focus();
        $("form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });  
        
        $("#join").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            if (name != "") {
                socket.emit("join", name);
                $("#login").detach();
                $("#chat").show();
                $("#msg").focus();
                ready = true;
            }
        }); 

        $("#name").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 13) {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                if (name != "") {
                    socket.emit("join", name);
                    ready = true;
                    $("#login").detach();
                    $("#chat").show();
                    $("#msg").focus();
                }
            }
        });  

        socket.on("update", function(msg) {
            if(ready)
                $("#msgs").append("" + msg + "");
        }) 

        socket.on("update-people", function(people){
            if(ready) {
                $("#people").empty();
                $.each(people, function(clientid, name) {
                    $('#people').append("" + name + "");
                });
            }
        });

        socket.on("chat", function(who, msg){
            if(ready) {
                $("#msgs").append("" + who + " says: " + msg + "");
            }
        });

        socket.on("disconnect", function(){
            $("#msgs").append("The server is not available");
            $("#msg").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });

// Sending the message (either by button click or enter)
        $("#send").click(function(){
            var msg = $("#msg").val();
            socket.emit("send", msg);
            $("#msg").val("");
        });

        $("msg").keypress(function(e){
          if (e.which == 13) {
            var msg = $("msg").val();
            socket.emit("send", msg);
            $("#msg").val("");
          }
        });

      });

    </script>

<body>
  <div class="container">

<div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
          <ul id="people" class="unstyled"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <ul id="msgs" class="unstyled">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="span5 offset2" id="login">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Your name" id="name">
            <input type="button" name="join" id="join" value="Join" class="btn btn-primary">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span5 offset2" id="chat">
          <form id="2" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Your message" id="msg">
            <input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send" class="btn btn-success">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you are getting as well ?

Comment: In the console: GET http://1.2.3.4:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js                 localhost/:5                                                net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the different `listen` calls.

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var socket = io.listen(1223, "1.2.3.4"); 
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

The third line has not the effect you expect. `io` is not listening itself. It uses the http server that is listening on port 3000.

Rather use this on the server

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

And in the client connect to port 3000 (or the port configured via the PORT environment variable.

```
var socket = io.connect("your.domain:3000");
```

If you want to listen on a dedicated port for socket.io, you have to create a second http server listening on a second port, and bind that one to socket.io.

Comment: Now its looking like this, doesn't work: var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = io.connect("your.domain:3000");

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);



server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

console.log('Server is running...');
var people = {};  

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

Comment: Of course, this won't work ! This code `var socket = io.connect("your.domain:3000");`is for the client side ! and of course, you have to replace 'your.domain' with your domain name or ip address.

Comment: Sorry but node.js and setting up servers are completly new to me. This is basically the first time I'm trying to do this

Comment: No problem. For me it was all new a few months ago too.

Comment: So its probably a newbie question.. But one the client side (my html file), how do I connect using the code you wrote? (var socket = io.connect("your.domain:3000");)

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out! Thanks @Lorenz Meyer